# iPhone - Core Data Questions?

Tags: iphone, core-data, primary-key

[image]

Above is my data model diagram.
Everytime i create a Car whcih contains a model and make, it adds a car object to core data.
The problem is that it also adds 1 make and 1 model to the core data, so i get duplicates.

for example, in the following code, it saves 1 car object 2 models, and 2 makes,
so I get a duplicate Make in my table (2 "Nissan").
How can i avoid this? is it possible to create primary keys?

**In the following example i want to assume that make and models already exists, and a car is only referencing to them, so how can I avoid inserting into make, and model, and only insert into car?**

```
- (void)MyCode
{
     [self AddCar:@"Nissan" @"Rogue"];
     [self AddCar:@"Nissan" @"Murano"];
}


- (void)AddCar :(NSString*)_make :(NSString*)_model
{
    Car *car = [[Car alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Car" 
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    Make *make = [[Make alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Make" 
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    make.name = _make;

    Model *model = [[Model alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Model" 
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]
               insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    model.name = _model;
    car.make = make;
    car.model = model;
    [self saveContext];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

The data model shows that the `Make` and `Model` entities each have a to-one relationship with `Car`. Therefore, there can be only one `Car` for each `Make` and only one `Car` for each `Model`. In other words, given that data model, Nissan can only make one `Car`. You probably want a to-many `cars` relationship in `Model` so that Nissan can make more than one `Car`. Same thing with `Make` so that there can be more than one `Car` with a given `Make`.

The way `NSManagedObject`s are inserted into the managed object context is incorrect. It should be done like this:

```
Car *car = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Car"
    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Finally, your code shows that a new `Make` and `Model` entity are created for each `Car`. If you are starting with the name of a `Make`, you probably want to search the managed object context for a `Make` that has a matching name. If found, just set the `make` relationship of the new `Car` to the `Make` entity that is already in the context. If not found, create a new `Make` entity and set up a relationship to that.

Comment: thanks, 1 more question, if instead of creating a make, and model for a car, i read them from the existing make, and models, does it automatically assign them to the new car object while saving?

Comment: No, you'll still have to assign them, e.g., `car.make = existingMake`.

Answer (score 1):

don't create new makes and models but use those stored already in core data.

Write a controller that searches for a make and model with NSPredicate. something like this:

```
- (id)modelNamed:(NSString *)searchName addIfMissing:(BOOL)add {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", searchName];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!results) { 
        LogError(@"Error [%s], %@, %@", _cmd, error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }
    if ([results count] == 0) {
        if (add) {
            // add model with new name...
            id newModel = ...
            return newModel;
        }
        else
            return nil;
    }
    return [results objectAtIndex:0];
}
```